# Error cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, werkzeug

not sure why the code is breaking down but am assigning 3 variables to a function call that are all used in the call and i keep getting an Nonetype error with the class function call.

i am trying to create a user and passing a success, user and message.

If success is true then it will then proceed to create and send the user an activation email

user is the user created.

message is if there is an error(there user has been created before and exists)

```
if email_address and first_name and last_name:
            #register user and check other params
            success, user, message = User.create(email_address=email_address, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)

            if success:
                # send activation email

                success, message = User.send_activation_email(email_address=email_address)

                if success:
                    return make_response(jsonify({"Message" : "Registration Successful"}))
                    #Todo include the correct url
                    #return render_template_with_translations("public/auth/register_success.html", **params)
                else:
                    return abort(403, description=message)
            else:
                params["register_error_message"] = message
                return make_response(jsonify({"Message" : params}))
                #return render_template_with_translations("public/auth/register_error.html", **params)
```

The class being called in the users.model

```
@classmethod
    def create(cls, email_address, password=None, admin=False, first_name=None, last_name=None):
        try:
            # check if there's any user with the same email address already
            user = db.query("Select * FROM User WHERE email_address = {}".formart(email_address))

            if not user:  # if user does not yet exist, create one
                hashed = None
                if password:
                    # use bcrypt to hash the password
                    hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(password=str.encode(password), salt=bcrypt.gensalt(12))

                # create the user object and store it into Datastore
                user = cls(email_address=email_address, password_hash=hashed, admin=admin, first_name=first_name,
                           last_name=last_name)
                user.put()

                return True, user, "Success"  # succes, user, message
            else:
                return False, user, "User with this email address is already registered. Please go to the " \
                                    "Login page and try to log in."
        except:
            print ("Error with application")
```

[image: errors]

Comment: Can you shor the stack trace of the error

Comment: Also if you get in your except clause you dont return anything so your create function will return None which you cannot unpack. seems to me like your code is failing somewhere in the try block so falling into the except block which doesnt return anything

Comment: @ChrisDoyle added a picture with the stack trace of the error

Comment: I suspect that you must be falling into your exception code which doesnt return any value. you can reproduce this error with simple code`a, b, c = None` gives `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object`. I would say in your exception code after you print app error call return like `return False, user, "application exception error"` That will mean that in all cases of your function returning it will always return 3 params to unpack, However if this is where its failing you will then need to trouble shoot why your try block is raising an exception

Comment: A picture of text is not necessary. Copy the text and paste it in a code block.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle the issue was in the try and except block as you stated. Cheers and thanks